# Detect "tab" keyboard event in Mobile Safari

Tags: javascript, mobile, safari

I'm trying to detect the keyboard event for when the mobile safari "prev" and "next" events are triggered.  I've tried listening in on the keydown, keyup, and keypress events on the inputs themselves but nothing gets triggered.  Is there a way to listen for those "tab" touch events?  Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Look into the history object. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API

Comment: I don't think those are browser back and forward buttons.  They act more like the "tab" buttons.

Comment: You're talking about the < and > symbols that the pink arrow is pointing at, correct? Those are back and forward history buttons.

Comment: yep! they seem to act as keyboard "tab" events that focus on the different input text boxes.